# How do I mine using Ripley?

Tags: space-station-13

I've gotten the hang of mining the asteroid as a shaft miner, and recently discovered Ripley in the charging bay.

I entered the exosuit, loaded an ore box in it and quickly set off to do some mining. However, even though a drill is attached I don't seem to be able to mine. How do I use Ripley too mine?

Comment: I've never been in a Ripley myself, but I think you have to lower/raise the drill first before you start mining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the drill in the exosuit interface menu, the one where you can choose the drill and the like.

Once you do that, everything you drill will be put in the ore box. All you have to do to drop that orebox is just use the exosuit interface and select the hydrolic thingy and press on the ore box to drop it.

Hope I could help.